# Image Animation and Swipe to change image in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image

[image]

How to switch the image like this one by one,its possible to do like tat in android.Can any one know help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the coverflow widget.

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html  here is a link to this

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Hardik Nadiyapara some time the  image not go one by one,one or two images are skipped.